# How to update and insert in the same time from table to another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

After checking two tables ,I'm trying to update common values  or insert them in table 2 , In fact, we suppose that we have two tables:

- Table A:

  Id     Name      LogIn    LogOut
- Table B (Filtered table)

  Id         Name     LogIn LogOut

So , My object is to insert from Table A the filtered data to the Table B ( filtered LogIn, LogOut , eliminate the duplication ).

This works fine, but I encountered a problem in the update statement query, so if I remove one row from the Table B, I didn't get this row ( insert the row again when I execute the Stored procedure that contains the insert and the update from Table A to Table B.)

```
declare @TableA table(Id nvarchar(55),logIn datetime,LogOut datetime)

begin

insert into @TableA(Id,LogIn,LogOut) exec Employee_getfilteredrecords @datefrom, @dateto

if exists(select o.Id from TableB o,@TableA r where r.date=o.date and o.Id=r.Id)

update TableB b set  b.id= r.id, logIn = convert(nvarchar(12),cast(r.LogIn as time),120), logout = convert(nvarchar(12),cast(r.LogOut as time),120)
FROM TableB b, @TableA r where b.id= r.id 

else 


    INSERT into TableB (
          Id,
          logIn,
          logOut
         
 )
 select Id,convert(nvarchar(12),cast(LogIn as time),120),convert(nvarchar(12),cast(LogOut as time) ,120) from @TableA
end
```

Comment: Have you already googled for the `merge` statement?

Comment: Your `IF EXISTS` statement is checking that _any_ of the rows match in `TableB` and `@TableA`.

Comment: I hope this , but the problem is that when the `IF EXISTS` Find the first element matched , it will update all rows , that was my problem.

Comment: @Tyron78 , could you form an answer with `merge` statement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641628/how-can-i-use-insert-with-select-from-other-table-in-a-merge-statement

Comment: @Tyron78 , Thank you so much , the `merge` statement fix my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using the `MERGE` statement. It helps you handle the following cases:

- record in source table matches a record in the destination table (update)
- record in source table does not match records in destination table (insert)
- record in destination table no longer found in source table (delete)